# Unable to connect apostrophe-cms with mongodb v3.4.7

Tags: mongodb, apostrophe-cms

I am new to mongodb and apostrophe-cms. I installed mongodb v3.4.7 (64bit) and apostrophe-cms (apostrophe-cli@2.1.3) successfully on my Window Server.

I created a apostrophe project with many pages and the website is up and running on my http://localhost:8080.

Now, the problem is: I see ony static content written in my xxx.html files located in

```
lib\modules\apostrophe-pages\views\pages
```

I do not get any content from the mongodb which is filled with *aposAttachments* and *aposDocs* etc. It is important to mention that the mongodb is **not** the original database. I copied a database from another apostrophe project and renamed it according to the current apostrophe project name.

Is that a valid thing to do, or an absolutely no-go area? Where do I tell apostrophe which database to use?

Comment: I refer to the problem described above ...
An important information to the existing problem is the fact that code snippets from the editable content slots appears where elements (text or images) of the mongodb are expected.

Comment: You mention that this is a copy of a database from somewhere else.

If you start with an empty database, or create new content in Apostrophe, does that content work fine?

How did you copy your database? That might be a non-Apostrophe-related problem but I'm happy to look.

Comment: With the fresh installation and the original apostrophe-cms and mongodb state I was able to add content myself. The content was displayed a) on the website and b) saved in the mongodb successfully. Later, I copied a external database collections from lets say *db_old* to my own *db_new* collection within my current project using **mongodump**. Instead of the database content, I see now the placeholder of code snippets from the editable content slots such as *{[{apos. singleton (data. page,' Pic',' apostrophe-images', {limit: 1}}}]}* and I cant edit the content anymore.

Comment: I'm wondering if the database copy is even related to that. What happens with a new database but *your* project?